# I can't import a snapshot using gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I can't resolve a SNAPSHOT dependency. I already published the project on [oss sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/sitrakary/unit-converter/1.0-SNAPSHOT/)

My main class:

```
package com.github.sitrakary.unitconvert.gui;

// import a class from the SNAPSHOT dependencies.
import com.github.sitrakary.unitconvert.Converter; // Can't resolve 'Converter'

public class App {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Gradle build file:

```
group 'com.github.sitrakary'
version '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.github.sitrakary',  name:'unit-converter', version:'1.0-SNAPSHOT', changing: true

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

}
```

Error

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'unit-converter-gui_main'
Information:javac 9.0.1 was used to compile java sources
Information:Module "unit-converter-gui_main" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:26/01/2018 12:30 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 3s 470ms
Error:java: Illegal char <:> at index 84: C:\Users\Sitraka\IdeaProjects\unit-converter-gui\Could not find com.github.sitrakary:unit-converter:1.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

[Image showing the dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl6wW.png)

Comment: You should provide more information - like what is the error you get, what should happen and what shouldn't. As it is now, your question is too broad / unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: mavenCentral and oss sonatype are two different repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding sonatype to repositories in my build.gradle file.

```kotlin
group 'com.github.sitrakary'
version '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // add sonatype repository
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.github.sitrakary',  name:'unit-converter', version:'1.0-SNAPSHOT', changing: true

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is with the java version. Your error indicates `javac 9.0.1 was used to compile java sources`, but your code has `sourceCompatibility = 1.8`. So it seems like the error might be coming from the fact that you are using a snapshot built with java 1.9 in a project using java 1.8.

Comment: What's wrong with using source compatibility with lower version of JDK, than used to build the code? javac has -s option that allows to define it.

Comment: I haven't worked with Java in over a year. I really don't remember the rationale for this answer.